# Do bond lengths change upon protonation of a molecule such as an H2O molecule?

Tags: acid-base, bond, protons

Wouldn't the hydrogen atom in a hydronium cation feel a greater proton repulsion force (nucleus-nucleus repulsions) from the oxygen atom and orient away from the oxygen atom to maximize the attractive force it has for the shared pair of electrons by minimizing proton repulsions?

Comment: The bond length is *definitely* different, but what is a “proton repulsion force”?

Comment: For a water molecule, the shared pair of electrons between the hydrogen and oxygen atoms tend to spend more time towards the oxygen atom resulting in a slight negative charge for oxygen atom and a slight positive charge for the hydrogen atom. Now, this means that electron that is bound to hydrogen is now farther away from the hydrogen atom than it would be if it wasn't shared with oxygen. From this perspective, I thought that there must be some other force preventing the hydrogen atom from moving closer to the shared pair of electrons and I thought that possible force was proton repulsions.